# Apache poi how to unhide sheet by password?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is it even possible to unhide sheet by password?
I hide my sheet by :

```
workbook.setSheetHidden(workbook.getSheetIndex("mySheet"), true);
```

and also it's protected by

```
sheet.protectSheet("myPassword);
```

and what i need is to show that sheet after unprotect by password. How can i do it?

Comment: If I understand you right, its not possible. AFAIK even excel itself doesn't offer that functionality

Comment: And there is not any workaround with this? It is not possible to unhide sheet by password in the other way?

Comment: Hidden and password protected are 2 completely different and separated functions. they don't work together in any way I know